# How to calculate the response time of RESTful web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, apache-commons

I am consuming an web service using Apache commons HTTP client, I want to calculate the exact response time, What will be the best way to get it?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a already exiting tool meant for measuring response time of an API, not build it internal to your app and preferably use one that can also scale load.

If you're using only `GET` requests without authentication you can try using Apache Benchmark (`ab` https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html).  It comes with `apache` and you can run concurrent requests to create load.

For more complex requests like a `POST`, look at running `jmeter`: http://jmeter.apache.org/ or `gatling` (http://gatling.io/#/)

Neither of these will address performance under *distributed* load natively, but several hosted services exist for distributed running of `jmeter`  tests like https://blazemeter.com.

IF you really want to build something yourself into your application (for logging/debuging purposes for example), look at the Apache Commons performance framework: http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-performance/

Or... if you really just want very rough 'finger in the wind' performance number, use your ApacheCommon client and call it or your script with `time` command line application (if you're running on linux or OSX).  This is messy though as it will lump the response time with the client app or any script you might be running to call the client.

Comment: New Blazemeter accounts are only available by invitation by another people. Could you  please send me and invitation? I'd like to use it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JohnAlexanderBetts I do not have an account.